# set windows service connection string on run time

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a windows service I set the ConnectionString from properties.setting it's work on my PC, but when I made the installation and install it on other computer how can I set new connection string. I think it will be manually but I don't know how.Thanks.

Comment: `set the ConnectionString from properties`?  post your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deploy your service it generates a file named "yourexe.config". If i am right about how you are setting up your connstring, you just need to change it in that file BEFORE you start the service.

Best regards,
Marco Alves.

Comment: thanks, it's work but now when I install the program in other pc show the error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. I was get this error also in my pc and I fix it, but in other pc it not work.Thanks.

Comment: could you post the code that is triggering the error?